# rearranging array values into a new array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have wrote this code which is supposed to grab the last 8 values in the array and reverse them and put in the first slots of the new numbs[] array. However I also want the { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4 } values in the numbersArray to be added after the last 8 values in the numbs[] array, without being reversed. This should be dynamic so if there are 24 values in the numberArray[], there should be 3 groups with the even groups values to be reversed.

```
numbersArray = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 };
int[] numbs =  new int[numbersArray.length];

for (int i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
        numbs[(i % 16) < 8 ? i : (8 - (i % 8) - 1)] = numbersArray[i];
}
```

Result:

```
numbs[] = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want the array to actually display:

```
numbs[] = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4]
```

Comment: So.. if there are two groups, you want the second group to be reversed, and put as the first group. The only thing that happens to the first group is just that is put in a second group. But.. When there are 3 groups, then the second is to be reserved and.. ? Put in a the first group? What happens to the other two groups? Does the third group just remain where it was?

Comment: The last group of a dataset should always be first in the new array. So the 3rd group should not be reversed because it is odd group. Then the 2nd group should be reversed in and put into the new dataset after the 3rd group and followed by the first group in the numbs[] array at the end.

Answer (score 0):

add this down of your code

```
for (int i = 8; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
    numbs[i] = numbersArray[i-8];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to use Arrays. Although it can done using Collections also easily.

There are constraints for below code.
Size of Array >= 16
Can be optimized further..

```
int[] numbersArray = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
int[] newArr = new int[numbersArray.length];

int x =8,y=8,j=-1;

for(int i = numbersArray.length-1;i>-1;i--){
  if(x!=0){
    newArr[++j] = numbersArray[i];
    if(x==1){y=8;}
    x--;
  }
  else{
    newArr[j + y ]= numbersArray[i];
    if(y==1){x=8;j=j+8;}
    y--;
  }
}

for(int v:newArr)
    {System.out.println(v);}

  }
```